# How to compare wrapped functions with functools.partial?

Tags: python, functools

If I define my function as below:

```
def myfunc(arg1, arg2):
    pass
```

then `myfunc == myfunc` will return `True`

But `functools.partial(myfunc, arg2=1) == functools.partial(myfunc, arg2=1)` will return `False`.

For unittest purpose, is there an easy way to test if the partial function is the one I expect?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Test if the `func`, `args` and `keywords` attributes are the same:

```
p1.func == p2.func and p1.args == p2.args and p1.keywords == p2.keywords
```

where `p1` and `p2` are both `partial()` objects:

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> def myfunc(arg1, arg2):
...     pass
... 
>>> partial(myfunc, arg2=1).func == partial(myfunc, arg2=1).func
True
>>> partial(myfunc, arg2=1).args == partial(myfunc, arg2=1).args
True
>>> partial(myfunc, arg2=1).keywords == partial(myfunc, arg2=1).keywords
True
```

There was a [bug filed in the Python tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue3564) to add equality testing to `partial` objects that does essentially that, but it was rejected on the grounds that not having an `__eq__` method shadows the behaviour of functions, which also are only equal if their `id()` matches.

Comment: Is there any good reason why `functools.partial` objects don't implement that in the standard `__eq__`?

Answer (score 3):

A helper function to compare

```
def partial_functions_equal(func1, func2):
    if not (isinstance(func1, partial) and isinstance(func2, partial)):
        return False
    are_equal = all([getattr(func1, attr) == getattr(func2, attr) for attr in ['func', 'args', 'keywords']])
    return are_equal
```